How to wisely choose the right polynomial $f(x)$ with $Cov(x,f(x))=0$?
Exercise
Let $X $ be the outcome of a fair die roll. Provide a polynomial $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ with $ Var[f(X)] > 0 $ such that $cov[X, f(X)] = 0$.
My approach
$f(x)=x^2-7x-\frac{119}{3}$ derived from
starting with a general quadratic $f(x)=a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0$
now for simplicity we would want

$\mathbb{E}[f(x)]=0$ so that

$cov[X,f(X)]=\mathbb{E}[X \cdot f(X)]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\mathbb{E}[X \cdot f(X)]$


by setting $a_2=1$ and solving the linear system of equations (1)+(2) we retrieve the above polynomial (if I computed correctly).
Anyways, this requires a lot of manual work since we yet have to show that the variance is positive.
My Question:
is there a smart/obvious choice for the polynomial in order to not have to do all these manual computations?

Any polynomial that is symmetric around $x = \frac72$ (i.e., any polynomial $f(x-7/2)$ where $f(\cdot)$ is even) will work.

Note that showing $f(X)$ has a positive variance just amounts to showing it's not almost surely constant.  In your case, that means you just need to find $i,j \in {1,2,3,4,5,6}$ such that $f(i)\neq f(j)$.  Alternatively, since the degree of $f$ is less than 6 and $f$ is not a constant, it can't have the same output for 6 values, so there's nothing really to compute.

Using $$\text{Cov}(X,f(X)) = E[(X-E[X])f(X)],$$ you can assume $a_0=0$.
That is, you have
$$E[(X-\frac72)(X^2+a_1X)]=0,$$
which does in fact yield $a_1=-7$.
It follows that $f(x) = x^2-7x$ works.
